# How to track and draw the route of the current location when the app is in background(not closed) in KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, routes, gps, drawing, background-service

My App is tracking und drawing the route of the current position to the google map when it is active(GPS position). But when the app closes and i open it after 1 minute, the route doesnt take the positions where i was, instead it takes a direct line from the last position. 
how can i get the exact route to the map? 
i´ve tried it with a background service, but failed.
I followed a tutorial for lat lng which gives the position in forground(with notifications), but only if the app is closed.
so, how can i get this running when the app is closed???( not killed!)
thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. You need to have the gps running in a service with foreground service enabled (so that there is a notification active while service is running). Additionally you may need to opt out of battery optimisation.

Comment: Okay...Thank you